# Making forces to work same on Different Resolutions

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

I am facing multi resolution issue in box 2d.

First I needed to make bodies multi resolution, I solved it by scaling the vertices by scale factor.

Now I need to make the forces to act same of all different resolution devices,
Is there any way to do it?

I want to make this line of code to work same on all devices

```
obj.getBody().applyForce( new Vector2(0, -220), obj.getBody().getWorldCenter());
```

Here 220 is the factor should I make it multi res by this formula

```
public float getY(float value) {
    y = (value / 540) * 100;
    return (y / 100) * CAMERA_HEIGHT;
}
```

Here 540 is the base resolution. I call getY(220) to make it multi resolution.

When I use this code on resolution 540*960 it works fine but when I change the device say of resolution 720*1280 the game acts real slow.
Can any one help me with this issue? I tried to explain my question.
Thanks in ADVANCE.

Comment: The value of the CAMERA_HEIGHT is based on the resolution of the device, right?

Comment: yes right, CAMERA_HEIGHT and CAMERA_WIDTH are resolution of the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You scale the graphics by setting your camera to something other than the device's pixel count.

Andengine will do everything else for the scaling.

All you need to get from the device is the ratio of x to y pixels.

In the example I have at this link, I just set one variable and everything is scaled to that.http://pastebin.com/WWGFvTVS

So you just decide what initial scale you want to work on, and do your Box2D stuff without worrying about scale.  You just have to scale the Camera that is looking at the scene.

I'm saying the same thing as these other guys, you just don't seem to be understanding them.

Comment: O yes, Thank you, Now I got you. Actually when other friends were explaining the solution I wasn't using the camera system you mentioned. Now I have scaled the camera and every thing is working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do not scale physics. Scale graphics. You should have physics coordinate system shared between each resolution to make your simulation the same on different devices.

Comment: I agree with Andrew - more precisely, I say pick a size (800x480, whatever), write to that, and let AndEngine scale the graphics using a properly configured RatioResolutionPolicy.

Comment: @jmr499485: not any size, but the size box2d is tuned to work with. There is a part about it in the manual

Comment: Graphics are properly scaling, I dont have issues with graphics now, what I am facing issues is with the forces, the forces are not acting same on all devices.

Comment: @JawadAmjad: because you are scaling physics. Like you said " I solved it by scaling the vertices by scale factor" - it's incorrect. Don't do it. Leave the physics totally the same on different devices. Scale graphics

Comment: @Andrew I am scaling graphics but there came an issue with bodies the bodies were not scaled. So I needed to scale bodies.

Comment: @JawadAmjad: take a look here http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

Comment: Thanks you Andrew unfortunately I am not able to understand Cocos code :( and also I cannot see any code regarding multi resolution there.

Comment: @JawadAmjad: PTM_RATIO is a constant that translates box2d units to graphics units. Just vary it on different resolutions

Comment: ok m giving it a try , will definitely let you know after applying it.

Comment: tried to vary PTM_Ratio but no luck, the bodies are now not same on all devices. Even after scaling graphics the bodies are not scaled. I am now not scaling bodies.